# Can I get a packing neighbor to stay in my Animal Crossing town?

Tags: animal-crossing-city-folk

I went on vacation last week and I've come home to Animal Crossing: City Folk to find that one of my neighbors is getting ready to move out of town.  It's to the point where his house is filled with packed boxes.

I sent him a couple letters yesterday, but it didn't seem to matter - he is still intent on moving.  Is there anything else I can do to ensure that he stays?

Answer (score 1):

From what I recall, you need to keep badgering them by talking to them until the conversation turns to the better, where they will consider staying or say something to that effect, though I don't think its 100%...we tried that once in addition with the letters and gifts attached, and they still left

Comment: Unfortunately I'm too late to save Puck, but I will try this next time a neighbor begins packing.

Comment: Alas, poor Puck, we hardly knew ye!

Comment: Lord, what fools these mortals be!